# Oracle - How to get the values of a column needed for range partitioning parameters

Tags: sql, oracle

For a table T with a column C on which I need to range partition the table, how do I get the partition values for a given number of required partitions? The column is incremental (by 1 or more) and not necessarily unique.

Example scenario:
Record count of table T is 100,000.
Distinct values for column C is 20,000.
Min value for column C is 1000.
max value for column C is 21000.

Given this information, how do I write a query to get the below result (that I can use as my partition values).

if 2 partitions:
10,000
21,000

if 3 partitions:
7,000
14,000
21,000

and so on..I don't want to assume the number of partitions, I need it to be a variable in the query.

Comment: Your results seem odd.  If the min value is 1000 and there are two partitions, wouldn't you want the breaks at 11000 and 21000 so that both partitions have 10000 values?  Rather than 10000 and 21000 where the first partition has 9000 values and the second has 11000?  If you do want equal ranges, it seems like you just want to divide the difference between the min and max by the number of partitions and add that to the lower value.  Is it really that simple?  Are you sure that you want to range partition rather than hash partition where data gets evenly distributed automatically?

Comment: I agree with your first statement. My requirement is simple yes but I'm trying to figure out a query that can get the exact record values as the column can increment by more than 1. Merely adding the (max-min)/part_number to the min value and so on could result in a value that doesn't exist in the column.

Comment: Why do you care whether the value you choose to partition by actually exists in the table?  If you want equal ranges, 1,000 - 11,000 works just as well if there are no values between 10,217 and 11,000 as if there are rows with 10,999, 11,000, and 11,001 in the data.  If you want to ensure that the values exist in the table, you probably won't get lucky that you can have N ranges of equal size-- what metric would you want to use to pick which unequal set of ranges to return?

Comment: Quick question, are you saying the value we use in "values less than(i)" clause of the statement doesn't have to actually exist in that column?

Comment: There is certainly no requirement that the value in the `values less than (i)` needs to exist in the table.  Otherwise, you'd have terrible issues if, say, someone deleted the last i row from the table without changing the partitioning scheme.

Comment: I honestly didn't know that, but makes perfect sense now that I think about it. So the idea you suggested 1st would definitely work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I came across NTILE and below seems to be working. Let me know if there are cases where this might not work.

```
select  part_num, max(column_name)as part_value from(
 select column_name, NTILE(X)OVER ( ORDER BY column_name) part_num FROM table_name)
group by part_num order by part_num
```

assuming X is the number of partitions I need resulting in part_num from 1 to X and part_value is what I would be using in the range partition syntax in the 'values less than' clause.